# How to have an updating prompt while waiting for input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the question is how to have an input function or stdin.readline function waiting for an input, while having an updating prompt i.e. The prompt contains the time in format HH:MM:SS and is refreshing every second like:

```
while 1:
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT) +  ' :>')
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

But as soon as you add an input there, of course the program waits until you write some input. The version of python I am using is 3.5.

I know I should use curses, but I am planing to write a cross-platform program and the only module I have found is clint, but it didn't have anything in the documentation on the updating prompt.

I have found something that got pretty close but has different problems:

```
def input_thread(L):
    x = input()
    L.append(x)

L = []
thread = threading.Thread(target=input_thread, args=(L,))
thread.start()
while 1:
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT) +  '>:')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now the problem remains is that when you type the input but do not press ENTER, the input on the next iteration remains but when you write something, the previous input gets replaced by the current one. Of course the previous inputs are still there in the argument L, so there is no lost input. I hope I didn't describe this to confusing.

If there is no easy way of doing this as it could be done with curses, I'm open to similar cross open tools. Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: Store `L` status in a variable and check  your on `while` loop for "what changed !".

Comment: @dsgdfg Maybe I wasn't specific. I can handle what I get in the input. The problem is, everytime the prompt refreshes, the input you typed without hitting enter, dissapears. If I print what happened in the previous iteration, then the string will always be visual on the command line.

Comment: don't need any thread if work together (in same cycle) . Otherwise need pause/lock thread for additional events.

Comment: You need another thread if you wish to have an updating prompt while waiting for an input. Input locks the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what I wanted, a few months ago but didn't answered my own quesiton.

To have a prompt with updating time, you need a separate threads that:

1. Updates the prompt with additional input
2. Catches your key strokes

The second thread handles every key-stroke and you can program it how to handle the pressed keys.

When pressing a key, the thread that updates the prompt adds the pressed keys. Also you have to configure some shortcuts for Return, Backspace, etc... to work as expected

I've got it to work and unfortunately... I don't like it. If anyone would like to see the code I will happily provide.